# Python pandas how to deal with operations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following problem which I am not sure how to solve with acceptable performance.

Example:

I have a list with all the close prices from stock between 2 dates, let's say
`close_price = [1, 2, 5, 3, 10, 1]`

And I also have an array with just True and False which has True if it's a buy single.
`buy_ind = [False, True, False, False, True, False]`

All of the abuse is found in pandas.DataFrame.

How can I say something like this without any for-loop preferable?

I wanna go over all the elements from close_price that are True in buy_ind (using np.where()) and I wanna check which one of them is meeting my conditions and then go to the next one.

And on the end, I will have an array with all the sell signals.

Can anyone tell me how should I solve this without using for-loop and just iterate over all the array and check the conditions? Or this is the only way?

**UPDATE:**

Example:

```
df['close'] = [1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2]
df['buy'] = [False, True, False, False, True, False]
df['indicator'] = [3.1, 5.3, 0.3, 0.1, 6.2, 8.5, 9.0]
df['sell'] = [False,False,False,False,False,False]
```

What I want is.

1. Loop overall 'close' prices
2. Find the first one which has True into the 'buy' column (for example in our case is value 4 from index 1)
3. Get the value from the 'indicator' column that is on the same index (in our case would be 5.3)
4. Check which of the following 'close' prices are going to meet some condition which is going to use the 5.3 as a parameter
5. Stop when you find the first value which meets the condition and set the index of 'sell' True

ex: if we start from the 'close' price 4 which has the 5.3 value of `indicator` accordingly. We will check all the prices that meet conditions(5.3) and if for example 'close' price 3 of index 3 is going to meet the
condition we will set the index from 'sell' True => [False,False,False,True,False,False]

6. Go to the next close price and repeat the process

Comment: I would make a dataframe. `df` with two columns for your data, then create a third column using `df['new column'] = df.apply(func)` where `func` is a function that takes a tuple of the values in the two original columns and returns whatever you want.  `apply` applies your function row by row

Comment: `.apply(func)` applies a function column by column. `.apply(func, axis=1)` applies a function row by row.

Comment: please add small samples of your input dataframes and also what the expected dataframe would look like

Comment: @SamSzotkowski and @CameronRiddle I don't know how to use `apply` for my case

Comment: @tdy I've added a small explication, if is not quite clear let me know, I will try to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of what you want:

For each row that has True in 'buy' column:

- Function checks that row's indicator against a list of all 'close' values beneath this row in the table
- Function returns the index of a row I should sell

Then:

- Update 'sell' of all rows whose indices were returned by the function

Input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['close'] = [1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2]
df['buy'] = [False, True, False, False, True, False]
df['indicator'] = [3.1, 5.3, 0.3, 0.1, 6.2, 8.5]
df['sell'] = [False,False,False,False,False,False]
```

```
def conditions(index, indicator, close_list):
    compare = indicator * 10
    for close in close_list[index+1:]:
        if compare > close:
            return index
        index += 1
    return -1

close_list = df['close'].tolist()
df['row_index'] = df.index

get_conds = lambda row: conditions(row['row_index'],row['indicator'],close_list) \
                        if row['buy'] \
                        else -1
df['sell_index'] = df.apply(get_conds, axis=1)
sell_inds = df['sell_index'].dropna().tolist()

df['sell'] = [ind in sell_inds for ind in df['row_index']]

>>> print(df)

   close    buy  indicator   sell  row_index  sell_index
0      1  False        3.1  False          0          -1
1      4   True        5.3  False          1           2
2      5  False        0.3   True          2          -1
3      3  False        0.1  False          3          -1
4      1   True        6.2  False          4           5
5      2  False        8.5   True          5          -1
```

And obviously you can drop the intermediate step columns (row_index and sell_index)

Comment: Thx for your answer but this is not exactly what I needed. Let me try to explain in other words.
I have a list of 'buy' which is going to tell me that where its True that meens its a good moment to buy a stock. But then I need to sell it for a profit, where
come in place my condition.
I want to check which is the next 'close' price that is going to satifice my condition, and if it is, I will set that value with true.

Comment: `buy = [False, True, False, False, False]`
`close = [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6]`
`indicator = [0.2, 0.6, 0.1, 9, 10, 11]`

`My BUY signle is flashin at price=3, indicator=0.6 and index=1`

Now I wanna start from the close[index:] until I found the first price which for example lets say is less then 10 * 0.6(value from indicator of index 2). 
And If it's true I will put a True in my sell array. In our case 5 is going to meet the condition.

On the end I will have.

`buy = [False, True, False, False, False]`
`sell = [False, False, False, True, False]`

Comment: So tell me if this is right: for each row in which `buy == True`, we want to pass that row's `indicator` along with all `close` values AFTER this row, to the `conditions()` function?

Comment: we want to pass just ONE value from the `indicator` which is found at the same index as `buy==True` along with all the close values AFTER that index to the condition. And the condition should check wether or not that specific value from `indicator` multiply by 10 is bigger than the current value `close` that we are checking.

Comment: I'm glad that you understand, thx for your help :)

Comment: Edited my answer.  Fingers crossed.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed :D, Thx you very much :)